# zsh completion with nested control functions

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I'm writing completion function for `zsh`. I took [`cargo` completion function](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/cargo/_cargo#L18-L36) as a basis for mine. For the most part it works fine except for `-h` and `--help` options. Completion ouput for these functions is unaligned and repeated multiple times (presented below). This only happens when [control functions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Control-Functions) (`_describe`, `_arguments` etc) are present in case structure.
Why this is happening and how can I fix this behavior?

Completion function:

```
#compdef test
_test() {
    local context state state_descr line
    typeset -A opt_args
    _arguments \
        "(- 1 *)"{-h,--help}"[Help]" \
        "1: :->command" \
        "*:: :->args"

    case $state in
        command)
            _alternative 'arguments:custom arg:(a b c)'
            ;;
        args)
            _arguments \
              "-a[All]" \
              "-n[None]"
    esac
}
_test
```

Shell output:

```
> test -[TAB]
--help
-h
-- Help
--help
-h
-- Help
--help
-h
-- Help
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just encountered the same issue. The solution is to return zero from your completion function:

```
#compdef test

_test() {
    ...

    return 0
}

_test
```

All completion scripts that I've seen use `ret` variable which is initially `1` and then set to `0` if any completion function succeeded:

```
#compdef test
_test() {
    local context state state_descr line
    local ret=1

    typeset -A opt_args
    _arguments \
        "(- 1 *)"{-h,--help}"[Help]" \
        "1: :->command" \
        "*:: :->args" && ret=0

    case $state in
        command)
            _alternative 'arguments:custom arg:(a b c)' && ret=0
            ;;
        args)
            _arguments \
              "-a[All]" \
              "-n[None]" && ret=0
    esac

    return ret
}

_test
```

I'm not sure why they do it, though.